# Как использовать в std::condition_variable функцию член класса?

Tags: многопоточность, c++11

В .h

```
class A{
    std::thread thread;
    std::mutex  mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool run;
    std::queue< ResourceData > queue;
public:
    bool resource_empty( void ){return !this->queue.empty();}
...
```

В реализации

```
while( this->run ){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(this->mutex);
    cv.wait( lk, /* Сюда нужно вставить указатель на функцию */
    this->resource_empty );
    // просто this->queue.empty не работает
    // cv.wait( lk, []{ return !this->queue.empty();} ); и так
}
```

Работает только если функция **вне класса** и **без параметров**.

Хочу чтобы поток ожидал пока поступят данные в очередь. Может быть тогда есть иной способ с использованием данных класса без std::condition_variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, всегда можно использовать метод wait без второго параметра.

Во-вторых, чтобы использовать внешнюю переменную в замыкании - ее надо сначала захватить:

```
cv.wait( lk, [this] { return !this->queue.empty(); } );
```

Писать `this->` необязательно - в лямбде так же, как и в любом другом месте, можно обращаться к членам this просто по имени. Но захватывать `this` нужно все равно:

```
cv.wait( lk, [this] { return !queue.empty(); } );
```

Также существует универсальный способ - захват всех необходимых переменных по значению:

```
cv.wait( lk, [=] { return !queue.empty(); } );
```

или по ссылке:

```
cv.wait( lk, [&] { return !queue.empty(); } );
```

Пользоваться этими способами надо с осторожностью: бесконтрольный захват переменных может привести к утечкам памяти или повреждению памяти. Но применительно к `cv.wait` использование `[=]` или `[&]` ничем не грозит.